# SQL statement that hangs DB

Tags: mysql

I was trying to cross reference 2 tables using the following query from myPhpAdmin app:

```
select A.*
from purchases A
where A.user in (
    select B.user
    from users B
    where B.ppi = 'Facebook Ads'
)
```

It accepted the syntax but the DB never returned. The users table is not small, 200k rows, but i run querys on it all the time so it shouldn't take that long.. Any ideas as to why this might not work? The query was stuck in the state:Sending data. I had to kill it because my database was broken at this point so I cannot run any other checks on this now and Im scared to try again :)

Running on mysql FYI.

What I really wanted was just to be able to operate on values in table purchases only when the same user id is present in the other table with the given ppi value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join and make sure, you have indices on `B.user` and `B.ppi`.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM purchases A
INNER JOIN users B ON A.user=B.user
WHERE B.ppi = 'Facebook Ads'
```

Comment: This worked in 1.4 seconds. Massive improvement from forever ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A join should be faster than a subquery.  Try this:

```
Select A.* from purchases A 
INNER JOIN users B on A.user = B.user  
WHERE B.ppi='Facebook Ads'
```